# android UI elements' visibilty not changing

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I've been writing an app for FTP file transfer and i need to hide a few UI elements and make a few visible on a button click.The visibility settings remain the same as when the app starts.They do not change.Any idea why?

here are my elements:

```java
ip= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipadd);
portt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
conn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectb);
pb= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
trans=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.transfer);
```

here are the settings at the starting of the app(onCreate):

```java
pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
trans.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
portt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
conn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

These settings are applied.
And this is the code for the function when the button is clicked:

```java
Ftp ftp;
errflag=false;
ip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
portt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
conn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
trans.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
while(!errflag) {
    try{
      ftp=new Ftp();
      String result = ftp.execute("hi").get();
      if(result.equals("Finished"))
          break;
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Everything in the code works fine except for the visibility of these elements.
The control enters the while loop and exits properly but doesn't change the visibility of the elements.And yes the function is invoked on button click,so it is in the UI thread,but i've still tried wrapping up the code in runOnUIThread method which doesn't seem to make any changes.
Any comments will be appreciated.

Asynctask code:

```
public class Ftp extends AsyncTask<String ,String,String>
{

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        try
        {
            String ipadd= ip.getText().toString();
            int port =Integer.parseInt(portt.getText().toString());
            Socket socket=new Socket(ipadd,port);
            //Button conn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.connectb);

            //conn.setEnabled(false);
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedOutputStream bo= new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(bo,true);
            String file=br.readLine();
            if(file.equals("Finished"))
                return file;
            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
            File f= new File(path, "/" + file);
            byte[] buff= new byte[1024];
            int len;
                pw.println("done");
                DataInputStream is= new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(f);

            Thread.sleep(1);
            publishProgress(file);
                while((len=is.read(buff))!=-1)
                {



                    fos.write(buff,0,len);

                }
            Log.i("status","Finsihed");


           /* else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"File already exists!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }*/
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            errflag=true;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enter a proper IP and port!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            nfe.printStackTrace();

        }
        catch(java.net.UnknownHostException un)
        {
            errflag=true;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enter a proper IP and port!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enter a proper IP and port!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            un.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(java.net.NoRouteToHostException no)
        {errflag=true;

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"There is no active server at the specified IP and port!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            no.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)

        {
            errflag=true;
            Log.i("this","error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Not Yet";
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... para)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(para);
        trans.setText("Transfering file: "+para[0]);


    }

}`
```

Then i made a new thread:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
    public void run() {
        while (!errflag) {
            try {
                Ftp ftp = new Ftp();
                String res = ftp.execute("hi").get();
                if (res.equals("Finished"))
                    break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and changed the function code to:

```
errflag=false;
            ip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            portt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            conn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            trans.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        /*ftp=new Ftp();
        String result = ftp.execute("hi").get();
        if(result.equals("Finished"))
            break;*/

        try {
            MyThread t = new MyThread();
            t.start();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: which one elements visibility you want to modify? all of this?

Comment: ip,portt,conn,trans,pb

Comment: What happens if you comment out the while block. Does it still not work?

Comment: is your ftp.execute function running in the main thread? Maybe you're blocking the UI before it gets updated

Comment: you're blocking the ui thread in while loop, so changing visibility means that views hierarchy will be redrawn on a next frame. so as you block ui thread, this redraw phase will never be reached.

Comment: @BilalNaeem i didn't check.It's the main code,but if it's entering the while loop,it definitely has to be executing the instructions above that ,right?

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin The changes are written before the while loop.I don't understand the loop could affect it

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi Ftp runs on an async task..but the button click function runs on main thread.

Comment: @sumanth post the asynctask code please

Comment: wait.i just commented out the while loop and it's working.Anybody know why?

Comment: @sumanth, there are no difference where you placed this code snippet, cause changing visibility is not an immediate operation. redrawn - is a scheduled procedure, executing on a main thread.

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin u were right,but could u explain why and the solution

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin thanks a lot . i understand now.But what's the solution?

Comment: move your while loop in another thread to release your UI-thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your help.I found the solution.Apparently,putting the heavy work on another normal thread wont change anything.AsyncTasks are designed for this purpose.
I read this article : https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/asynctask-helps-avoid-anr
and i put the while loop inside another asynctask class and made UI changes in the "onPreExecute()" and put the loop in the "doInBackground()".It worked like a charm.
This is my code:

```
class HeavyWork extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        trans.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        portt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        conn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        start();
    return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void a)
    {
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        trans.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        portt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        conn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        trans.setText("Waiting for files");
    }


}
```

The start method is:

```
 public void start()
{
    while (!errflag) {
        try {
            Ftp ftp = new Ftp();
            String res = ftp.execute("hi").get();
            if (res.equals("Finished"))
                break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and then i changed the onClick method to:

```
errflag=false;

        /*ftp=new Ftp();
        String result = ftp.execute("hi").get();
        if(result.equals("Finished"))
            break;*/

        new HeavyWork().execute("hi");
```

But it seems u can't call an asynctask from another asynctask thread.so u need to call it from a UI thread.In order 
to do that,i removed start from doInBackground and pasted it in onPostExecute,as it runs on UI thread,like this:

```
class HeavyWork extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        trans.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        portt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        conn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls)
    {

    return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void a)
    {
        start();
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        trans.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        portt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        conn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        trans.setText("Waiting for files");
    }


}
```

Small edit:
Apparently,you cannot update progress if u call the second async task on UI thread.SO,i deleted the asynctask and i removed the loop on asynctask,instead, put the loop in asynctask.and i had to remove all the code above the object of ansyctask in the func and paste them in onPreExecute and onPostExecute method.
That's it.It worked.

Thanks a lot guys.Especially Alexander and Nicola.You're wonderful :)

Comment: It's okay putting ui operation in onPreExecute callback, but unPreExecute works in the Main Thread as well as your previous code. Pretty confusing to me :), happy that now it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

I consider, you should move your while loop in another thread.
Changing visibility means that views hierarchy will be redrawn on a next frame and it [visibility] will be taking into account only on a next drawing iteration. so as you block ui thread (in a while loop), this redraw phase will never be reached.

UPD: you should release your UI thread, so just move while loop in another thread.

```
ip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
portt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
conn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
trans.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        errflag=false;
        while(!errflag) {
            try{
              ftp=new Ftp();
              String result = ftp.execute("hi").get();
              if(result.equals("Finished"))
                  break;
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @sumanth, if it helps you, mark this one answer as a correct one, please

Comment: i moved it to another thread and started it ,but it didn't work

Comment: @ sumanth, the whole while loop? just try the code, which I have posted below in solution

Comment: hmmm, its java 8, if this syntax looks wrong just update lambdas to anonymous class invocation. `() -> {}` to `new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { ... your while loop here... } }`

Comment: yeap, it looks like this, cause while you're commenting the `while` loop it looks fine.

Comment: yes @alexander..the visibility settings and the loop

Comment: Checkout my answer.And thanks for the help and your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute your ftp method in a worker thread like below, probably you're blocking your UI to be updated.

```java
Ftp ftp;
errflag=false;
ip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
portt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
conn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
trans.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
try {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // a potentially time consuming task
            while(!errflag) {
                ftp = new Ftp();
                String result = ftp.execute("hi").get();
                if(result.equals("Finished"))
                    break;
            }
        }
       }).start();

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: check it out nicola

Comment: it should not work as well, cause you have `while` loop in a top closure of invocation. it will block UI thread as well, cause while `!errflag` true, it will infinite create new threads.

Comment: Checkout my answer Nicola .Thanks for your help and time :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run only following in main thread and see if it helps.

```
ip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
portt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
conn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
trans.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```